# partnership problems

Tags: recreational-mathematics

A,B and C started a business by investing Rs 7,000, Rs 5,000 and Rs 3,000 respectively. If they earned a profit of Rs 9,000 , find the share of A ?

Note: Rs = Indian Rupees

Answer (score 3):

You need to make proportion.
$\frac{A}{X}=\frac{B}{Y}=\frac{C}{Z}=\frac{15000}{9000}$

$X=\frac{7000\cdot9000}{15000}=4200$

$Y=\frac{5000\cdot9000}{15000}=3000$

$Z=\frac{3000\cdot9000}{15000}=1800$

Test the solution:
$X + Y + Z = 9000$

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the agreed model of sharing the profits.
E.g. the founders could have negotiated equal shares of the profit, in this case A would receive Rs 3,000.

Another (possibly more common) model is to share profits in the same proportions as the made investments.
A's investment quota is 
$$
\frac{7,000}{7,000+5,000+3,000} = \frac{7}{15} \approx 47\% .
$$
Using this model A would receive
$$
\mbox{RS }9,000 \, \frac{7}{15} 
= \mbox{RS } 4,200 .
$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Hints are not uncommon on this site, especially if the problem is very easy. To make everybody happy, I extended it to a full solution.